# Light Mono Installation

Tags: mono

The mono installation provided at mono-project.com comes packed with several libraries, such as gkt, making the installation quite large (~280MB or so).

Is there any way to provide users with an installation of "just" the mono environment? I am targeting Windows, MacOSX and Linux.

Comment: On which OS do you plan to install Mono? Please make it clear.

Comment: Windows, MacOSX and Linux.
It's not for me, it's for distribution purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications) which merges your application, the libraries it uses and the Mono runtime into a single executable image. See under "Bundles" in that page.

If you do this though, it may mean that you are distributing LGPL code with all that this implies.

If you are distributing your app for Mac OS X, there is also [MonoMacPackager](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager) which offers more advanced support for this. I think they have done a bunch of work in the linker to really minimize the amount of Mono that you have to include. It will actually remove unused code from assemblies that you reference.